# Как правильно вести версии API сервиса для ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Всем привет, подскажите, как правильно вести версии апи на уровне логики.
Использую ASP.NET Core, Библиотеку MediatoR, подход CQRS и проект на чистой архитектуре.

На уровне контроллеров у меня выглядит так и все понятно.

```
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v2")]
public class CalculationsController : WebApiControllerBase
{
    [Obsolete]
    [HttpPost]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK, "200", typeof(Response<IEnumerable<ProductResponseBase>>))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromBody] GeneralProductQuery request)
    {
        return Json(await Mediator.Send(request));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [MapToApiVersion("2.1")]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK, "200", typeof(Response<GeneralProductResponseV2_1>))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetV2_1([FromBody] GeneralProductQueryV2_1 request)
    {
        return Json(await Mediator.Send(request));
    }
}
```

На уровне приложения вышло так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И не понимаю, правильно ли организовываю версионность, что дописываю версии в имена классов или в методах   каких-то сервисов?
Так и реализовывают API сервисы или есть другой подход?

Comment: Можно версии сделать пространствами имён. Тогда имена классов и методов можно оставлять теми же в новых версиях.

Comment: Лично мне оказалась очень полезной книга Modern API Design with ASP.NET Core 2, Fanie Reynders. Глава 9, раздел Versioning. Рекомендую к ознакомлению.